# Persistent volumes on public node

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, marathon, dcos

I'm trying to install a containerized app using Marathon to a public slave. It's all working fine until I decide to use persistent volumes. I then get the message

> Resident apps may not define acceptedResourceRoles other than "*" (unreserved resources)

I there a work-around for this or am I simply misunderstanding the role of public slaves? I'd like to access this app at some point via `service.mydomain.com`, hence I thought I'd need a public node.

Comment: I guess it would make sense to only use the public slaves for something like marathon-lb and host the other apps on private slaves. It's also a potential matter for security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message you see, `Resident apps may not define acceptedResourceRoles other than "*" (unreserved resources)` is admittedly not very helpful and you were on the right track. Effectively, [persistent volumes](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/persistent-volumes.html) in DC/OS are not allowed on nodes with the role `slave_public` (the public nodes) and hence you'll need to use [Marathon-lb](https://dcos.io/docs/1.7/usage/service-discovery/marathon-lb/usage/) as an edge router (in `external` mode) to expose the app that uses PV (and schedule it on a private agent).

Comment: Thank you - I had probably misunderstood the notion of `public`. I've got marathon-lb on a public node now and everything else for now on private ones. Works great!